# Java socket, client hangs when get input from server output

Tags: java, sockets

i have a socket in client that connects to an server to send and receive String, uses writeUTF() and readUTF() to read and write to socket, when i write a string from client to socket and read them on server then it's work. But when server receive string from socket and write "flag" to socket to read them on client then client hang at read line. Here is my code.

Server

```
public void run(){
    DataInputStream input = null;
    try{
        output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        while((true)&&(this.active)){
            String receive = input.readUTF();               
            String[] str = receive.split("@");
            if (str[0].equals("get_list")){                    
                output.writeUTF("flag");                  
            }

        }
    }catch(IOException ex){
    }
```

Client

```
public void run(){
   DataOutputStream output = null;
    try{
        output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        output.writeUTF("get_list@");          
        String receive = input.readUTF();   //Hang at this line
        System.out.println(receive);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
```

Comment: Probably you need to `output.flush()` before that.

Comment: Add `output.flush()` to both server and client right after each `output.writeUTF()` or any other write to output if you have it.

Comment: you mean after output.writeUTF("flag"); ?. I try but not work

Comment: Debug your client and the server at the same time. Seems that there is unbalanced read/write issue. Your client waits for information, but your server does not plan to send this information. FAQ, how to launch multiple instances of Netbeans IDE: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqMultipleIdeInstances

Comment: I meant both after `output.writeUTF("get_list@");` and after `output.writeUTF("flag")`.

Comment: write `output.flush();` after `output.writeUTF("flag");` in server code...and then check..

Comment: I have tested this and I received the flag response from the server. This leads me to believe the problem is in a different part of your code. Post code where sockets are created, initialised and connected.

Comment: *Never* ignore an exception, except in this case `EOFException`. Fix and advise any changes, i.e. stack traces of exceptions caught. You also need to add some tracing here: the result of `String.split(),` for example. @GáborBakos `DataOutputStream` is not buffered, and neither is anything else here: *ergo* `flush()` will do nothing.

Comment: I was debug both and it's still hang at that line. If i run both server and client on localhost then no problem, but i got client hang when i run them on lan with 2 laptop. Server can receive all string client send but client not